# When Deploying Contact fields to Salesforce sandbox, data is no longer synchronized with MC

Tags: marketing-cloud, deployment, marketing-cloud-connect

We use MCConnect to synchronize data between Salesforce sandbox and Marketing cloud.
When updating, adding, and deleting multiple fields using change set to Contact object of Salesforce sandbox without pausing the synchronization of MC Connect, data is no longer synchronized.

The updated content of the Contact field is as follows.

- Change of data type (date → date time)
- Change of data type (text → formula text)
- Change data type (check box → select list)
- Change of data type (lookup → text)
- Change data type (Text → Selection list)
- Change of data type (Selection list → Multiple selection list)
- Change of data type (Selection list → Text area)
- Change of data type (date time → formula (check box))
- Number of digits changed
- Change / add list value of selection list field
- Add new field
- Delete field

Details of the circumstances when it is no longer synchronized are as follows.
After deploying with change set, we noticed that Salesforce sandbox data was not synchronized with MC with automatic synchronization every 15 minutes, and when we performed manual synchronization with MC, we originally had 250 contact data in Sync DE, but that contact data was 0 became.

There are 250 Contact data in the Salesforce sandbox during the above.

Why the Contact data is no longer synchronized? The data of other objects are synchronized.

Also, in the sandbox that is synchronized with MC with MC Connect. Is there a safe procedure for updating field information etc. of Salesforce sandbox?

Comment: I also want to know the reason why it can not be synchronized, but I'd like to know how to restore contact synchronization anyhow.
Child objects (custom objects) of Contact are also synchronized. Is it necessary to delete the data of the child object once?

I am in serious trouble. Please lend me your wisdom.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You changed Data Types of fields that were synched. In data Sources/Data designer it had previous Data Types for the synched fields. So you'd either need to change Data types in Data Designer/Data Sources--I can't do somehow though. If its' the same case for you try Pausing Synch From data Sources and then Synch again.
If both don't work:Try **Unsynch** that Object and **synch** that object after a while. Let me know if you're able to resove the issue. There's also a Best practices link here https://dreamevent.secure.force.com/articleView?id=mc_co_implement_synchronized_data_sources_best_practices.htm&type=5

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  
Is it a best practice to take the following steps?  
  
1. Pause synchronization in Data Sources  
2. Make object change in Salesforce sandbox linked with MCConnect  
3. Resume synchronization in Data Sources

Comment: Any other way to think to synch correct data with change in fields data type in source, is not in my awareness. Let me know if above solution worked for you.